# Best way to handle XAML windows security dialog popup with Webdriver (Windows 10 + IE 11)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, ui-automation

Currently I am trying to automate a web application using C# + Webdriver which requires AD authentication. While trying to access the application, I get the windows authentication dialog in IE 11.

In the past, I have used various tools like Auto IT/Robots to handle the older version of the dialog box. However the new one, which is in XAML, does not support any of this.

Even any image based solution will do for me (except sikuli for some reasons)

[image: Windows Security Dialog in XAML]

Here, I need to select "More Choices" and then select the "Use another user" and enter the credentials. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any programming question? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @PauloMiraMor Thanks for pointing it out, I have updated the question. Currently am using the C# + Webdriver to automate the application and I need help in writing code to automate the authentication dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This dialog can be automated using Windows UI Automation accessibility. The only catch is you can't read the password field but you can certain inject text to the username and password fields safely, click on the More Options icon etc.

I haven't really used AutoIt for this purpose, but they have a module for this - https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/